# Using Attention-OCR model (tensorflow/research) for extracting specific information from scanned documents

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model

I have a few questions regarding the Attention-OCR model described in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03549.pdf

**Some context**

My goal is to let Attention-OCR learn where to look for and read a specific information in a scanned document. It should find a 10 digit number that is (in most of the cases) preceded by a descriptive label. The layout and type of documents vary, thus I concluded that without using an attention mechanism the task is unsolvable due to the variable position...

My first question is: am I interpreting the model's capabilities right? Can it actually solve my problem? (1)

**Progress so far**

I managed to run the training on my own dataset with about 200k images of size 736x736 (pretty big, though the quality isn't that high and scaling it down more would make the text unrecognizable). Unfortunately, the machine I have at my disposal only has one GPU (Nvidia Quadro M4000), and time is a significant aspect. I need a proof of concept soon, so I figured that I could try to overtrain the model with a significantly smaller dataset, just to see if it is able to learn.

I managed to overtrain it with 5k images - it predicts every image successfully. But I have some concerns regarding my interpretation of this result. It seems like the model hasn't successfully memorized where to look for the desired information, but just memorized all of the strings disregarding whether they are actually written somewhere in the document or not. I mean, it's not very surprising that the model memorized it all, but my question is what image amount threshold must be exceeded for the model to start generalizing and actually learning the attention? (2)

**Spatial attention**

Another thing I'd like to address is the spatial attention mechanism. In the early stage of implementing the model I assumed that the spatial attention mechanism described in the paper was already included and working. Some time ago I stumbled upon an issue in the tensorflow-repository created by Alexander Gorban (one of the developers of Attention-OCR), where he stated that it was disabled by default.

So I turned it back on and realized that the memory usage became unbelievably high. The spatial dimensions of the Tensor including the encoded coordinates changed from

> [batch_size, width, height, features]

to

> [batch_siz, width, height, features+width+height]

That caused the memory consumption to jump by the factor of ~10 (taking the magnitude of images into account) -> can't afford that! Resulting in my third question: Is the spatial attention mechanism necessary for my task? (3)

**Bonus question**

Is it possible to visualize the silency and attention map with disabled coordinate encoding?